# Define max available RAM size

Tags: laptop, memory

Is that possible to determine maximum memory (RAM) size on my computer?

As you know there are a lot of mother boards that do not support memory beyond some upper board limit. I would like to increase memory for my laptop (**Samsung R40 plus**) but it is too old (near 5 years) and it has a lot of configurations so do not push me on official documentation, because maybe I have another configuration.

**P.S.** I know about 4Gb memory limit for 32 bit PC.

Answer (score 1):

According to Crucial's memory tool, your system can handle up to 2gb total, with 1gb maximum per slot.

http://www.crucial.com/uk/upgrade/Samsung-memory/R+Series+Notebooks/R40-upgrades.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how much RAM your computer can't handle. However I think its important to note that most applications **do not** have the capability to user more than 4GB. There are exceptions i.e if you are working on big image files or using virtual machines.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Well thanks but my P.S. note is talking about that somehow...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it should be posted as a comment at best.